# Russian encoding trouble in Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a problem with Russian encoding when using Redux Store.

I use ReactJS and Redux-Starter-Kit. When I use Russian in React code itself, everything is Ok. But when I retrieve Russian strings from store - I see unreadable set of symbols. The problem concerns only Chrome - in FireFox everything is Ok.

I switch of any retrieving code and reduce my code to only this:

```js
const store = configureStore({reducer: rootReducer})
```

I watch state in Redux Dev Tools.

Where to dig?

Comment: JS operates on UTF-8 encoding so there is hard to break anything. do all the characters are "not readable"? then check if font you use provides glyphs for cyrillic(just change font to different one).

Comment: The problem is not in Redux. I really don't understand, wtf is going on. I hardly guess when it has begun. I get rid of any redux and simply do `React.DOM.render( <div> Работа  </div>,document.getElementById("app"));` and it's Ok. But when I assign `test="Работа" and then `React.DOM.render( <div> {test}  </div>,document.getElementById("app"));` , I get unreadadble text. And only in Chrome.

Comment: try. different. font.

Comment: I don't use any explicit font declarations. And I don't know how to do it. In fact, I used Roboto and material-ui for react library and use their recomendations like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />` But now I've deleted this from my index.html.

Comment: It's eventually became Ok. I absolutely don't know why. I've tried to change fonts in scripts, in browser -nothing helped. I have test project in another directory. So I played there. And somehow I've decided to delete babel-loader from webpack config and inserted file-loader. As a result example stopped working. Ok. I've returned babel-loader. And example unexpectedly became working with correct cyrillic in Chrome!!  Moreover, when I've returned to main directoty and run dev server - it's also became Ok in Chrome. I've touched nothing in there. Not a bit. Why???

Comment: have no idea. sometimes Chrome just goes crazy on its own(say, Developer Tools doesn't stop on breakpoints anymore) until it's restarted. May it be your case?

Comment: I’ve restarted chrome. I’ve rebooted system - nothing changed. But when I did that senseless manipulation - I got what I’ve got.

Comment: By the way,  I’ve discovered that Babel escapes text in JSX, when not in curly braces. That was the reason why I’ve got correct output when Not used variable in JSX. And I’ve copy-pasted unreadable sequence in hex editor from chrome - and it was not UTF-8. I’ve tried to establish some regularity - and had failed.

Comment: sounds strange. if you get to reproduce that in stable way maybe it makes sense to report into Babel repo, what do you think?